# TypeScript: Passing a typed object to a function that accepts restricted but general parameters

Tags: typescript, types, parameter-passing

I want to write a function that only works with Plain Old Data objects (because I want to use postMessage) and then I want to hand objects to that function:

```js
// plain old data can only be bool, number, string
// or an array or an object composed of plain old data
type PodArray = Pod[]
type PodObject = { [index:string]:Pod }
type Pod = boolean | number | string | PodArray | PodObject

// all this works:

let test1:Pod = 1
let test2:Pod = "two"
let test3:Pod = [3, 3, 3]
let test4:Pod = {4:4}
let test5:Pod = {1:1, 2:"two", 3:[3, 3, 3], 4:{4:4}}

// this doesn't:

function send(data:Pod){
    postMessage(data, "")
}

interface MyType{
    key1:number
    key2:string
}

let data:MyType = {key1:1, key2:"2"}
send(data) // fails because Index signature is missing in type 'MyType'
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIAcBsEMEsB24D20Am52wC63AMazIqLQCe4ARgKbj4DOOATkgOYA094iArgLa1mHUBGL1mzWJRTN6JKgCsaBHIRT9IKBjUwoAZlDhJUGLLljAc5SHQAKKdAEFJ08AF5wD9AG0AulY29o4A8koqap4A3uA%20SOg0AB4AXEysiGx%20yd7gAL6Btl6OHjwCQuAAPuBp7JVFzq6UVd5hyqrAovTQ0OA4ABbwDOAA7rIA1gzJHdA0ajg0TACM2cWei8Azcws4AEwrmJ4ARDijhxuzvdsAzPslPldcD%20BXAZuXTAAst9FfH-lv8yYAFZvuAostFlw9sdTo9kvdHo8-FwvlFfrl8p1%20oMsCgFogAOQ4KbAfS8RCqeCkao0RDoAAU2Dw%20wAlFFgOBOVBtDgALILBiwNg0RkWLiHQ4s4CYpDzZj6WAEOi88gAFSC7K54DGNHIyz4ghozA5XJ15D2NQy0umFyZsGSKvVhWiZohXDN0J2h3yOjporwLPAYHACvg0CGtCIvB04AAknSktV4GxELheMw6Dj%20IMGLUTNZCgTHUECcAgA)

This makes sense because MyType doesn't extend Pod and it shouldn't because I don't want anything else than key1 and key2 in it.

How do I write a function that takes general parameters of a certain category and rejects others and then hand in parameters that have much narrower types?

---

Edit: I now have an approach that I found via more or less trial and error:

```js
type PodObject<T> = { [K in keyof T]:Pod<T[K]> }
type Pod<T> = T extends boolean | number | string? T:
    T extends Function? never:
    T extends Object? PodObject<T>:
    never

function send<T>(data:Pod<T>){
    postMessage(data, "")
}

interface MyType{
    key1:number
    key2:string
    key3:MyOtherType
}

interface MyOtherType{
    key4:number
    key5:number[]
}

let data:MyType = {key1:1, key2:"2", key3:{key4:3, key5:[1, 2]}}
send([{data, 5:5}])
send({})
send(function(){}) // Error
send(1)
send([1,2,3])
send({a:4, b:[1,"x",3], data, f:()=>{}}) // Error
```

I designed this thinking that the type of the argument will be handed into the conditional chain as T. However, since I don't "call" the Pod thing with a defined T but it tries to match the result of the conditional chain of Pod to the argument type (so it should actually work backwards), I don't really understand why this works and I am not sure it actually does what it's supposed to do. Any help still appreciated.